# Problems with Creating PDF Using JS and HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, jspdf

I am using angular, node, express, and  html.

I am trying to implement the code found here http://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/rxPNpG. However, unfortunately the buttons do not call any function on click. No code has changed, so I am a little lost as to how to get buttons functional. Buttons are the update-preview-button and download-button found below. 
Here is HTML button section:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<html ng-app="app">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
<% include headerpdf %>
<% include navbar %>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                            <button id="flyer_preview_btn" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" tabindex="9">Update preview</button>
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="form-group text-right">
                                            <button id="flyer_download_btn" class="btn btn-default btn-xs btn-block" tabindex="10">Download</button>
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>

            </div>
```

Here is relevant JS:

```
            update_preview_button = $('#flyer_preview_btn'),
            download_button = $('#flyer_download_btn');

    // preview can be displayed?
    if (navigator.msSaveBlob) { // older IE
            update_preview_button.prop('disabled', true);
            can_display_preview = false;
            preview_container.replaceWith(
                    '<div class="no_iframe">' +
                    '<div>' +
                    "The preview can't be displayed" +
                    '</div>' +
                    '</div>'
            );
    }
              // restoring buttons
             download_button.prop('disabled', false);
             if (can_display_preview) { update_preview_button.prop('disabled', false);
                                    }
                            };
                            user_img.src = img_data.src;
                    };
            //!pdf builder
            var createPDF = function(update_preview) {
                    /*
            update_preview:
                ==> true: shows pdf online
                ==> false: downloads the pdf
        */
               // ****************************
               // output
               if (update_preview) {
               preview_container.attr('src', pdf.output('datauristring'));
                    } else {
                            pdf.save('flyer ' + flyer_title + '.pdf');
                    }

            }; // end createPDF

            // !buttons
            update_preview_button.click(function() {
                    createPDF(true);
            });

            $('#flyer_download_btn').click(function() {
                    createPDF(false);
            });

    } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
    }
   })();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at the code on the link you posted, I would say that the javascript isn't running because you are calling jsPDF. Have you installed that library before running your code?

Comment: Yes, I have.  `<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jspdf.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Is the code above the EXACT code you are running? It is hard to gleam any good info on incomplete clode. For example, you have a catch statement without a try. From my point of view, the buttons aren't calling afunction because the javascript is failing on load. Here is a jsfiddle with the basic functions associated with the buttons that works: https://jsfiddle.net/bqu3zf26/

Comment: This is not the exact code, but rather snippets. I posted this previously, and many suggested I reduce the code. Is there anyway I can get all of my code to you ?

Comment: Well, actually my code is essentially this http://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/rxPNpG . However, it is no longer working on my end

Comment: can you maybe list your changes then? Put yours in a jsfiddle or Pen it, so I can see the differences.

Comment: Only difference is I deleted some of the comments in the former's html.

Comment: Well, I took from the code in codepen and was able to make working copy. I removed the first paragraph from the html, and that was about it. The preview doesn't work in both cases, but the button does call the function.

https://jsfiddle.net/Lbhayp76/

Comment: Okay, I copied your js in the fiddle and replaced mine -- but, it still doesn't work. This leads me to believe it is something else in the environment. Would calling my angular app have something to do with it ?

Comment: Possibly. Can you save a jsfiddle with your code so I can check it out?

Comment: I have quite a large amount of code, would prefer to github it -- does this sound appropriate to you

Comment: Ok, I think it is the fact that you removed some of the color and price options from your code. I couldn't pinpoint what, was killing it, but you are calling from an id doesn't exist, and the js breaks when it tries to set read "undefined".

Comment: Okay, I think it didn't work before the removal of those options -- but I will see. Thank you

Comment: Unfortunately, I added back those elements and this did not aid the situation

Comment: OKay, so I got it to work. However, now when I do try to delete those options it does not work. Can I just delete it on backend so it won't have anything to look for ?

Comment: I think the biggest issue is in the createPDF function. You will have to comb through the code and see what it is calling for those options. You could also just do something fun on scratch and not try to retrofit your form into it. The library has documentation on how to use it. This is where you are on your own for customization.